# MODX Evolution. It is possible to get Template Variable ID in template?

Tags: php, modx, modx-evolution, modx-templates, template-variables

I need to know which ID the Template Variable (TV) has, to put it into a form in the template.

Something like this:

```
<input type="text" value="[template_variable_id]" />
```

Does MODX Evo have some special tag for it, which can be used in templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s because $modx->resource is *always* the currently loaded document. If you’re calling a snippet, you need to pass in the current ID:

```
[[!mySnippet? &resourceId=`[[*id]]`]]
```

Snippet **mySnippet**

```
  $resource = $modx->getObject('modResource',$resourceId);
    $template = $resource->get('template');
    echo $template;
```